# Make Foxit-Reader fonts available to use in MS word

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-office, fonts

I'm using currently Foxit Reader as the default PDF reader into my Windows machine. While writing text, I noticed that Helvetica font could be used, as into the image below.

[image]

This font is not installed into system, so it's something exclusive for the Reader itself. I've tried to search into the Foxit folder for some font directory, unsuccessfully. Is there any way to use this font into other software like MS Word, maybe by exporting it into my personal Font folder?

> I know that any font could be installed, but I want to understand how this software uses a font which is not installed system-wide, neither into the user font folder. Helvetica while installed system-wide gives lots of trouble in Chrome, Firefox and many other softwares: so I just want to use it in Word in the same way Foxit does.

Comment: Try a free Helvetica variation, e.g. https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/36452/helvetica

Answer (score 0):

[Helvetica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica)
is a trademarked typeface sold by Monotype Imaging which holds the license on the
Helvetica family. It comes loaded on most Macs and in Adobe applications,
but not on Windows.

There are many free alternatives to Helvetica and some are better matches than others.
Most commonly used are Arial and Swiss.

The Helvetica font is bundled with Adobe applications in a format that is not evident
to extract and install in Windows. You will not find it in TTF format anywhere
in the Adobe installation folders.
It may have been pirated already from Adobe, but that's not a subject that can be
discussed on our site.

Adobe applications therefore need to use it with font software that is built
into the application, not from the "C:\Windows\Fonts" folder.

You can buy one of the many commercialized
[Helvetica variants](https://www.myfonts.com/search/helvetica),
if that's your choice.